# how logstash-input-elasticsearch Incremental collect?

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, logstash

I have my logstash settings file using:

```
query: '{"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "now-3d/d","lte": "now/d"}}}]}}}'
schedule: "* 0 * * *"
everyday 00:00:00 collect start !
```

if the user logstash process exits and in a few days the logstash process starts.

It is difficult because of the processing of the period not collected.

So, I tried using the find logstash-input-elasticsearch function 'Incremental collect'. but I did not see it.

Comment: could you please try to reformulate your question and problem? it's hard to understand your problem right now